# Can't set up synced_folder with :owner and :group set

Tags: macos, vagrant

When I set up the synced folder without the `:user` and `:group` using the following syntax, it works as expected:

```
config.vm.synced_folder "..", "/home/vagrant/repo"
```

If I try to also set `:user` and `:group`

```
config.vm.synced_folder "..", "/home/vagrant/repo", :owner => 'vagrant', :group => 'httpd'
```

I am greeted with an error:

```
Vagrant was unable to mount VirtualBox shared folders. This is usually
because the filesystem "vboxsf" is not available. This filesystem is
made available via the VirtualBox Guest Additions and kernel module.
Please verify that these guest additions are properly installed in the
guest. This is not a bug in Vagrant and is usually caused by a faulty
Vagrant box. For context, the command attempted was:

getent group httpd

The error output from the command was:
```

I updated the `VirtualBox` to 6.0.20 and also downgraded to 5.2, installed `vagrant-vbguest` using `vagrant plugin install vagrant-vbguest`. On the guest, I also ran `sudo yum -y install kernel-headers kernel-devel` The error persist. What would be the fix?

- Vagrant version is 2.2.6,
- I am running `config.vm.box = "generic/centos7"`
- on OSX 10.14.6

Answer (score 0):

On centos 7, it is not the `httpd` user that is running `Apache`, but `apache` instead.